# getting com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLDataException: when fetching result set using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I am trying to fetch data from MerchantTerminalConfig. When i am executing the method getting error on colimn 3 which says '5.677755704167E12' in column '3' is outside valid range for the datatype INTEGER. As per the query the 3rd column is store id which is declared as string in model class ::

The Dao method code:

```
            public List<MerchantTerminalConfig> getMerchatStoreTerminalList(int userId,
                        String storeId) {
                    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                    List<MerchantTerminalConfig> merchantStoreTerminalList=new ArrayList();
                    try{
                        Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(MerchantTerminalConfig.class);
 #### Fetching result set #####                     merchantStoreTerminalList=criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("merchantId",userId)).add(Restrictions.eq("storeId",storeId)).list();

                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return merchantStoreTerminalList;

                }
```

The Model class are :

```
            package com.mtaka.finsol.model;

            import javax.persistence.Column;
            import javax.persistence.Entity;
            import javax.persistence.FetchType;
            import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
            import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
            import javax.persistence.Id;
            import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
            import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
            import javax.persistence.Table;

            @Entity
            @Table(name="merchant_terminal_config")

            public class MerchantTerminalConfig {

                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
                @Column(name="id",unique = true, nullable = false)
                private int id;

                @Column(name="merchant_id")
                private int merchantId;

                @Column(name="terminal_code")
                private String terminalId;


                @Column(name="terminal_desc")
                private String terminalDesc;

                @Column(name="store_code")
                private String storeId;


                @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
                @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id", nullable = false,insertable=false,updatable=false)
                private MerchantProfile merchantProfile;

                @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
                @JoinColumn(name = "store_code", nullable = false,insertable=false,updatable=false)
                private  MerchantStoreConfig storeConfig;


                public MerchantStoreConfig getStoreConfig() {
                    return storeConfig;
                }

                public void setStoreConfig(MerchantStoreConfig storeConfig) {
                    this.storeConfig = storeConfig;
                }

                public MerchantProfile getMerchantProfile() {
                    return merchantProfile;
                }

                public void setMerchantProfile(MerchantProfile merchantProfile) {
                    this.merchantProfile = merchantProfile;
                }

                public String getTerminalDesc() {
                    return terminalDesc;
                }

                public void setTerminalDesc(String terminalDesc) {
                    this.terminalDesc = terminalDesc;
                }

                public int getId() {
                    return id;
                }

                public void setId(int id) {
                    this.id = id;
                }

                public int getMerchantId() {
                    return merchantId;
                }

                public String getTerminalId() {
                    return terminalId;
                }

                public void setTerminalId(String terminalId) {
                    this.terminalId = terminalId;
                }

                public void setMerchantId(int merchantId) {
                    this.merchantId = merchantId;
                }

                public String getStoreId() {
                    return storeId;
                }

                public void setStoreId(String storeId) {
                    this.storeId = storeId;
                }



            }
            package com.mtaka.finsol.model;

            import java.util.HashSet;
            import java.util.Set;

            import javax.persistence.Column;
            import javax.persistence.Entity;
            import javax.persistence.FetchType;
            import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
            import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
            import javax.persistence.Id;
            import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
            import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
            import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
            import javax.persistence.Table;

            @Entity
            @Table(name = "merchant_store_config")
            public class MerchantStoreConfig {

                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
                @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
                private int id;

                @Column(name = "merchant_id")
                private int merchantId;

                @Column(name = "store_name")
                private String storeName;

                @Column(name = "store_code")
                private String storeCode;

                @Column(name = "address1")
                private String address1;

                @Column(name = "address2")
                private String address2;

                @Column(name = "city")
                private String city;

                @Column(name = "state")
                private String state;

                @Column(name = "country")
                private String country;

                @Column(name = "postal_code")
                private String postalCode;

                @Column(name = "pos_Message")
                private String posMessage;

                @Column(name = "creation_date")
                private String creationDate;

                @Column(name = "address1_Lat")
                private String address1Lat;

                @Column(name = "address1_Long")
                private String address1Long;

                @Column(name = "address2_Lat")
                private String address2Lat;

                @Column(name = "address2_Long")
                private String address2Long;

                @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "storeConfig")
                private Set<MerchantTerminalConfig> terminalConfig=new HashSet<MerchantTerminalConfig>(0);


                public Set<MerchantTerminalConfig> getTerminalConfig() {
                    return terminalConfig;
                }

                public void setTerminalConfig(Set<MerchantTerminalConfig> terminalConfig) {
                    this.terminalConfig = terminalConfig;
                }

                public String getAddress1Lat() {
                    return address1Lat;
                }

                public void setAddress1Lat(String address1Lat) {
                    this.address1Lat = address1Lat;
                }

                public String getAddress1Long() {
                    return address1Long;
                }

                public void setAddress1Long(String address1Long) {
                    this.address1Long = address1Long;
                }

                public String getAddress2Lat() {
                    return address2Lat;
                }

                public void setAddress2Lat(String address2Lat) {
                    this.address2Lat = address2Lat;
                }

                public String getAddress2Long() {
                    return address2Long;
                }

                public void setAddress2Long(String address2Long) {
                    this.address2Long = address2Long;
                }

                public String getCreationDate() {
                    return creationDate;
                }

                public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {
                    this.creationDate = creationDate;
                }

                @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
                @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id", nullable = false,insertable=false,updatable=false)
                private MerchantProfile merchantProfile;

                public MerchantProfile getMerchantProfile() {
                    return merchantProfile;
                }

                public void setMerchantProfile(MerchantProfile merchantProfile) {
                    this.merchantProfile = merchantProfile;
                }

                public String getAddress2() {
                    return address2;
                }

                public void setAddress2(String address2) {
                    this.address2 = address2;
                }

                public int getId() {
                    return id;
                }

                public void setId(int id) {
                    this.id = id;
                }

                public int getMerchantId() {
                    return merchantId;
                }

                public void setMerchantId(int merchantId) {
                    this.merchantId = merchantId;
                }

                public String getStoreName() {
                    return storeName;
                }

                public void setStoreName(String storeName) {
                    this.storeName = storeName;
                }

                public String getStoreCode() {
                    return storeCode;
                }

                public void setStoreCode(String storeCode) {
                    this.storeCode = storeCode;
                }

                public String getAddress1() {
                    return address1;
                }

                public void setAddress1(String address1) {
                    this.address1 = address1;
                }

                public String getCity() {
                    return city;
                }

                public void setCity(String city) {
                    this.city = city;
                }

                public String getState() {
                    return state;
                }

                public void setState(String state) {
                    this.state = state;
                }

                public String getCountry() {
                    return country;
                }

                public void setCountry(String country) {
                    this.country = country;
                }

                public String getPostalCode() {
                    return postalCode;
                }

                public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
                    this.postalCode = postalCode;
                }

                public String getPosMessage() {
                    return posMessage;
                }

                public void setPosMessage(String posMessage) {
                    this.posMessage = posMessage;
                }

            }
```

The exception is :

```
            Hibernate: select this_.id as id19_0_, this_.merchant_id as merchant2_19_0_, this_.store_code as store3_19_0_, this_.terminal_desc as terminal4_19_0_, this_.terminal_code as terminal5_19_0_ from merchant_terminal_config this_ where this_.merchant_id=? and this_.store_code=? and this_.merchant_id=? and this_.store_code=? and this_.merchant_id=? and this_.store_code=?
            org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
                at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:100)
                at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
                at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2235)
                at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
                at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
                at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:118)
                at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1597)
                at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
                at com.mtaka.finsol.dao.UserDAO.getMerchatStoreTerminalList(UserDAO.java:167)
                at com.mtaka.finsol.serviceImpl.UserDetailServiceImpl.getMerchatStoreTerminalList(UserDetailServiceImpl.java:160)
                at com.mtaka.finsol.action.CreateStoreTerminalAction.validate(CreateStoreTerminalAction.java:50)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doBeforeInvocation(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:261)
                at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
                at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
                at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
                at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
            **Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLDataException: '5.677755704167E12' in column '3' is outside valid range for the datatype INTEGER.**
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:999)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.throwRangeException(ResultSetImpl.java:7819)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.parseIntAsDouble(ResultSetImpl.java:7062)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2623)
                at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2734)
                at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.get(IntegerType.java:51)
                at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:184)
                at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:173)
                at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:126)
                at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2114)
                at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1404)
                at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1332)
                at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1230)
                at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:603)
                at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
                at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
                at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
                ... 66 more
            Hibernate: select this_.id as id19_0_, this_.merchant_id as merchant2_19_0_, this_.store_code as store3_19_0_, this_.terminal_desc as terminal4_19_0_, this_.terminal_code as terminal5_19_0_ from merchant_terminal_config this_ where this_.merchant_id=? and this_.store_code=? and this_.merchant_id=? and this_.store_code=? and this_.merchant_id=? and this_.store_code=? and this_.merchant_id=? and this_.store_code=?
```

Comment: Please take time to format your questions.

Comment: Can anyone answer this its urgent i am stuck with this from last 2 days

Comment: the problem is the value you are getting in string variable storeId is float value. Before adding it in criteria put following line 
`storeId = Integer.valueOf(storeId).toString();` or you can use Math.round() function.

Comment: @user550076: Check which datatype is your column in database.

Comment: Its Varchar in database

Comment: Thanks for reply Parth. But it is string type value both  in database and in in model. I have tried this but it didnot work

Comment: if i try to fetch data in my model class like this it works:   Object object[] = (Object[]) iter.next();
    MerchantTerminalConfig config=new MerchantTerminalConfig();
    config.setId( (Integer)object[0]);
    config.setMerchantId(((BigInteger)object[1]).intValue());
    config.setStoreId((String) object[2]);
    config.setTerminalId((String) object[3]);
    config.setTerminalDesc((String) object[4]);
    terminalList.add(config);

Comment: I think hibernate is confused and trying to convert varchar to numeric since the column is containing numeric string. Have anyone else faced this issue before